# Global Class for SQL enumerated objects

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a tool crib VB.NET project, my first real one, so I'm struggling with a few things.  In my SQL database I have a few tables that translate into enumerated fields.  For example I have code and code type tables.  I have a code type with CodeTypeID = 2 and description = Tool Status.  These are used to track the location of a tool; Shop, In Transit, On Site, Out of Service, etc.  I've set up enumerations for some of these.

```
Enum CodeType
    User = 1
    ToolStatus = 2
    Repair = 3
    OutOfService = 4
End Enum
ToolStatus
    Shop = 5
    Reserved = 6
    InTransit = 7
    OnSite = 9
    ReturnTransit = 10
    OutOfService = 11
    Repair = 12
End Enum
```

The problem is if I change a code in SQL I then have to edit my enumerations as well.  In the SQL tables I am only storing the CodeID and join to the code table to get the description.  Other than an enumeration, I haven't found a good way to load these tables when the project opens that will allow me to code as easily, for example ToolStatus.OnSite to return the number 9 to my SQL table.  It just seems inefficient to me.  I always try to code my SQL procedures so if something changes I don't have to go and edit a bunch of procedures and would like to do the same here, especially as a simple addition of a new code could force a version update.  Is there a better way to do this?  I have searched the Internet and haven't found anything that really works as well as enumeration.

Example Code:
In the following code both OnSite and ReturnTransit are enumerations.
I'm moving items between two datagridviews, a Source and a Target DGV.  Also  updating the underlying shared datatable.

```
        Dim cbo As ComboBox = sender
        With cbo
            Select Case .Name
                Case "cboPeeps"
                    dvgFilter = "N"
                Case "cboToolbox"
                    For i As Integer = 0 To dtTools.Rows.Count - 1
                        dtTools.Rows(i)("dgvFilter") = dtTools.Rows(i)("dbFilter")
                    Next
                    If cbo.Items.Count > 0 Then
                        filter = "ToolboxID=" & .SelectedValue.ToString & " And ToolStatus=" & OnSite
                        filter += " And UserID=" & .SelectedItem("UserID").ToString
                    End If
                    dvgFilter = "T"
            End Select
        End With
    End If
    Dim result() As DataRow = dtTools.Select(filter)
    For i As Integer = 0 To result.Count - 1
        result(i)("dgvFilter") = dvgFilter
        If result(i)("dgvToolStatus") <> OutOfService Then result(i)("dgvToolStatus") = ReturnTransit
    Next
```

Comment: There are some ideas in [Best method to store Enum in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2646498/1115360).

Comment: You probably don't need `Enum`s at all, if you code it right. A table is a close enough analog. Why do you think you need enum? Post some code which shows a reliance on enum which can't be replaced with a SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

I was, of course, trying to make this way too difficult.  Simple solution along these lines.

```
Public Class Crepair
Public repairID As Integer
Public techID As Integer
Public repairCodeID As Integer
Public acceptedDate As Date
Public remarks As String
Public isComplete As Boolean
```

End Class

```
        With nRepair
            .repairID = row.Cells("RepairID").Value
            .techID = row.Cells("TechID").Value
            .repairCodeID = row.Cells("RepairCodeID").Value
            .acceptedDate = row.Cells("AcceptedDate").Value
            .remarks = row.Cells("Remarks").Value
            .isComplete = row.Cells("IsComplete").Value
        End With
```